# What's the fastest was to load Font Awesome?

Tags: performance, font-awesome, cdn, pagespeed

I'm wondering how will Font Awesome load faster.

Should I use the JavaScript code or the CSS? Where should I put it in my HTML file? If I use the JavaScript code, what options should I use?

Here is a screenshot of the Font Awesome CDN interface when creating an embed code :
[screenshot of the Font Awesome CDN interface when creating an embed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF95K.png)

For now, I'm using a JavaScript file and I don't understand why Google PageSpeed tells me to "Remove the JavaScript resources that block the display" although I put the script juste before the `</body>` closing tag...

NB : I'm using the [Font Awesome CDN](https://cdn.fontawesome.com).

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: The fastest way to load font awesome is when you have loaded it once and then it keeps coming from your browser cache.

Comment: Actually I'm using GitHub Pages and they doesn't seem to use browser cache...

Answer (score 0):

Currently the fastest way of loading the font awesome is using cloudflare CDN.
Use this if you are on WordPress.

```
function add_font_awesome() {
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-css-new','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
};
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_font_awesome');
```

Additionally, you could edit font awesome files to remove unnecessary elements too, but it's a waste of time. Also you could load font awesome file in the footer instead of header to have a better score in Google pagespeed.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better to use CSS, and include it in the head of your HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you explain it please?

Answer (score -1):

Im using a different technique with a way better result.
Loading only a set of selected icons that im using in that particular website.
Its better than loading the all icons at once like in fontawsome
Im using this tool: [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)